# Is it possible to delete small islands from a geojson/topojson file?

Tags: geojson, topojson

Is there a way to remove small islands from my topojson file?

I currently have islands that belong to countries like Spain and portugal, but I don't want to display these small islands. I tried geojson.io but deleting these islands results in everything being deleted that belongs to the country, so including the mainland in Europe, which is the only part that I want to keep.

Comment: You probably want a GIS program such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Open the topojson map file in text editor. Split it in new lines with string ']],[['.
Then find a multiPolygon objects that you want to reduce.
Take a note of arc numbers in this MultiPolygon.
Now look on list of arcs.
Each arc is a small part of polygons/multiPolygons. Each arc has an ID, which is their order in file. 
If you count them, then you can see which arcs are used in your MultiPolygon that you are trying to reduce. 
In general small islands/areas are represented by very small arcs (length of points in arc definition).
By modifying list of arc IDs in your Main MultiPolygon you can switch them off from map.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using this GeoJSON online tool.

http://geojson.io/

I uploaded my TopoJSON file and then selected the island I wanted to delete then clicked "Delete feature".

After that I copied the JSON text back into my file. I had to make sure to keep the first part of my file so that it still worked in the code:

`{"type":"Topology","objects":{"states":{"type":"GeometryCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},`

I only pasted the "geometries" section. Then it worked!